# How can I add Boon or Jackson JSON parsers to Android project with Gradle?

Tags: json, jackson, gson, android-gradle-plugin

I would like to know how can I add Boon or Jackson parser to an android project using Gradle?

I found how to do so with GSON but couldn't find anything with Boon or Jackson.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Here's what have in my `dependencies` section in my `build.gradle` file for **Jackson**:

```
compile (
    [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.4.1'],
    [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-annotations', version: '2.4.1'],
    [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.4.1']
)
```

If you're trying to use jax-rs, you'll also need a few more:

```
    [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs', name: 'jackson-jaxrs-base', version: '2.4.1'],
    [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs', name: 'jackson-jaxrs-json-provider', version: '2.4.1'],
    [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module', name: 'jackson-module-jaxb-annotations', version: '2.4.1']
```

Comment: Why do you use that group "thing" into the sample compile?

Comment: It Worked for me i just had to add                                         packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }

Comment: Note that jackson adds almost 10k methods to the project. Might be an issue if one is concerned about dex method limit (64k).

Comment: @Kokusho Yes, and each "exclude" statement should be on a separate line... otherwise the error **Cannot invoke method exclude() on null object** appears.

Answer (score 105):

@Baldy answer is the same as:

```
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.10.1'
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.10.1'
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.1'
```

Following android studio conventions. You can find the up to date version at: [Maven Central Repository](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ccom.fasterxml.jackson.core).

Comment: Recent versions of Android Studio use the keyword `implementation` instead of `compile`
`
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.7.3'
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.7.3'
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.7.3'
`