# JSON to Java parser-Android

Tags: java, android-studio

I am doing a JSON to Java Object parse.

I changed my build.gradle at Android Studio as:

`compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.7.2'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.7.2'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.7.2'`

`packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }`

Even after these above changes, my imports are not working. Please help.
[image]

Comment: where did you get the compile string to use? Can only find maven imports.
Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25265407/how-can-i-add-boon-or-jackson-json-parsers-to-android-studio-with-gradle). this might help you

Answer (score -1):

Put this on your gradle file:

```
compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.0.1'
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hey, I used it like you suggested. Still same with the imports. Its not going through.